# In windows even small bytes leak showing high commit memory in resource monitor why it could happen?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, window, virtual-memory

We have an 64 bit application running on windows, for the fact we know it is leaking very few bytes of memory in the c++ code.But for a setup which has 16gb physical ram and 32gb pagefile.sys. Resource monitor is showing commit memory as 22gb and 900 MB in working set used by our process.

I knew for every process os will create virtual address space in pages and that number of addresses that will be depend on the 32 bit or 64 bit .I also knew that os will swap pages to disk i.e. pagefile.sys for running other apps.In windows i think page size is 4kb, **what i want to know is if one byte has leaked in a page of 4 kb  in physical ram , then after swapping to disk does it will show as 4kb is used instead of one byte by the process or not ?**

Comment: Even when you have no memory leaks memory that is freed by your program does not normally get released back to the operating system until your program exits. This makes resource monitor useless for detecting memory leaks.

Comment: so you are saying if 10gb is allocated by the process , that 10gb  will be not release until that process exits ? Then just consider if we have 4gb ram and 8gb pagefile ,if our process used 10gb , then only 2gb will be used by other apps ?

Comment: This is all implementation defined as the C++ standard has nothing to say about this. But in a typical implementation of the C++ runtime, allocated memory is not returned to the O/S until the program exits. On the other hand if you are allocating memory with calls to the Win32 API then the situation might be different.

Comment: okay...what is your comment on this "what i want to know is if one byte has leaked in a page of 4 kb in physical ram , then after swapping to disk does it will show as 4kb is used instead of one byte by the process or not ?"

Comment: I don't know, but I would imagine that it would show 4kb used.